# Relation between CPU's clock speed and clock period

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-speed

In this slide, things looks a little off to me. Clock cycle time or clock period, is already time required per clock cycle. Question is, does the word `Clock Rate` makes sense?

[image]

It also says, `Hardware designer must often trade off clock rate against cycle count`. But, they are inversely related. If one increases Clock speed, the clock period(time for per clock cycle) will reduce automatically. Why there will be a choice?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clock Rate simply means frequency, which the reciprocal of the time of a single clock cycle, so the equations make perfect sense.

Regarding the second question, cycle count is the same as "CPU Clock Cycles"; it is not the same as clock period or time per clock cycle.

Comment: But, then `Clock rate` is same as `Clock Speed`, just in different words. Why write x/x = 1? & then where does the trade off come in? (theoretical explanation would be comfortable)

Comment: The trade off is between _clock rate_ and _cycle count_, which are not in inverse relation.

Answer (score 4):

First things first, [slides aren't always the best way to discuss technical issues](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/powerpoint). Don't take any slide as gospel. There's a huge amount of handwaving going on to support gigantic claims with so little evidence.

That said, there are tradeoffs:

- faster clocks is usually better: get more integer or floating point operations done per second
- but if the faster clock doesn't line up well with external memory clocks, some of those cycles might be wasted
- slower clocks might draw less power
- faster clocks allow an operating system kernel to get more work done with every wakeup and return to sleep *faster*, thus they might draw less power
- faster clocks *might* mean some operations take more clock cycles to actually execute (think of the supremely deep pipelines of the Pentium IV -- branch mis-predictions were very costly -- despite the faster clock cycle than the Pentium III or Pentium M, in the real world, speeds were very similar for the two processor types.)